# Reflexive property in java Equals method

Tags: java, reference, equals

I am reading up on how to properly override the equals in Java, and ran into this sample. My first thought is that it would pass the reflexive property, but apparently it doesn't.

It basically returns false because of this line: `if(this != tc) return true;`

But isn't checking the same instance tc1, so tc1.equals(tc1), wouldn't it be passing a copy of the reference tc1, meaning they both are pointing to same TestClass object, and thus this and tc1 are essentially pointing to same object?

```
class TestClass {
    int someVar;

    TestClass(int i) {
        someVar=i;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object tc) {      
        if (tc instanceof TestClass && this.someVar == ((TestClass) tc).someVar) {
            if (this != tc) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return 1;
    }
}


public class HashDemo {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        TestClass tc1 = new TestClass(20);
        System.out.println(tc1.equals(tc1));
    }    
}
```

Comment: So if they are not equal, they are equal?

Comment: How can something "return false" from a line of code that says `... return true;` ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, this code does return false due to this line "if(this != tc) return true;"

Comment: @Sotirios, thanks for noticing. I actually meant the example to do something different, I will adjust the example.

Comment: @user1529412 It's not just that if condition, it's returning false due to the else condition immediately after. If you compare an object to itself using your `equals` method, it will return false because you explicitly test to return false in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have some of your if statements turned around.

Conventional equals method here would look something like this.

```
public boolean equals(Object that){
   if (this == that) {
      return true;
   }

   if (that instanceof TestClass && this.someVar == ((TestClass) that).someVar ) {
     return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is clearly not the right way to override the equals method, but it allows you to point the difference between "==" and "equals" on Objects

The egality between two references is done with the " == " operator.
The equals method is used to test the egality by values, that's why you can override it depending on your functionnal needs.

Regarding your code :

- tc1 == tc1 -> TRUE
- tc1.equals(tc1) -> FALSE